# Are these expressions equal?

Tags: javascript

Is this

```
const value = test ? value1 : value2;
```

equal to this?

```
const value = test && value1 || value2;
```

Are there any cases when they are not equal. (vars may be not booleans)

Comment: I don't think they're equal, if `test=true, value1=0, value2=1`, you get `0` at first but `1` at second.

Comment: the are not equal. very different. consider `test = "hello"`, `value1 = 5`, `value2 = 4`; the first would give you `5`, the second `hello5`, also, you'd only get `value2` in your second example if test or value1 have a falsey value

Comment: Wouldn't some quick tests using dummy values for test, value1, and value2 give you your answer?

Comment: Also, (and I might be wrong) but surely you wouldnt have a `const` that is conditionally set?

Comment: Try this case: `test = true`, `value1 = 0` and `value2 = 1`. It will be clear that the two forms are not equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first expression means:

> When `test` can be evaluated to `true`, then `value` is `value1`, otherwise `value` is
>   `value2`.

While the second means:

> When `test` AND `value1` both can be evaluated to `true`, then `value`
>   is `value1`, otherwise `value` is `value2`.

So when you give a `value1` that will be tested to `false`, they behaves different.

So when `value1` is `false, null, undefined, null, 0, NaN, ''(empty string)`, no matter what `test` is, value would be `value2`.

You can see [Truth, Equality and JavaScript](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/#more-2108) in what condition a value will be tested to `false`.

Answer (score 2):

They're not equal. In the first case, value will be assigned value1 or value2 based solely on the value of test. In the second case, if value1 is falsy, value will always be assigned value2.

Answer (score 2):

`const value = test ? value1 : value2;`

This is basically `value = value1` when test evaluates to true, and `value = value2` when test evaluates to false;

`const value = test && value1 || value2;`

this, on the other hand, will first check if `test` evaluates to true, then check if `value1` evaluates to true. Thus, if `value1` is a "falsy" value, `value` will equal `value2` even if `test` evaluates to true.

Answer (score 0):

```
const value = test ? value1 : value2;
```

can be converted to

```
const value;
if(test) {
    value = value1;
} else {
    value = value2
}
```

**AND**

```
const value = test && value1 || value2;
```

has no further simplification.

Here `value`, `test`, `value1`, `value2` **has** to be `boolean` **OR** it should have a **truthy/falsey** value (As mentioned my *@atmd* in comments).

Now, it is pretty clear that these 2 are **very different**

Comment: that's not totally correct, `test`, `value1`, `value2` don't have to be boolean, as long as their value is truthy/falsey

Comment: @atmd Thats correct. I will correct my answer. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: @atmd - All values in JavaScript are either truthy or falsey.